# How to scroll to a span element inside a div in React, so it is always visible and not overflown

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

There is a div with a bunch of spans inside of it like so:

```
<div id="wordDisplayWrapper">
  {words.map((word, i) => {
    if (i === idx) {
      return (
        <span key={i} className={"currentWord"}>
          {word}
        </span>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <span key={i} className={classes[i] || "word"}>
          {word}
        </span>
      );
    }
  })}
</div>;
```

The spans will overflow off the div, and overflow has been set to `overflow-y: hidden;`, this is the CSS:

```
#wordDisplayWrapper {
  height: 5.5em;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

The currentWord changes, and as it indexes forward, it overflows the div. I would like the div to scroll to this currentWord automatically, but I have not been able to find a way to do this. How should I go about this in React?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may target the element to scroll using a a html selector / refs and call `scrollIntoView()`. Call `scrollIntoView(true)` if you want the current word to be at the top of the container.

More about `Element.scrollIntoView`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

If you want a transition for the scroll, add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` css rule to the container div.

About `scroll-behavior`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Aside from the scroll-behaviour: smooth;, which is very laggy at maybe 2fps or so.